# Serilog.Sink.LogEntries doesn't work when run on mono on Ubuntu

Tags: mono, serilog, logentries

I want to use Serilog together with LogEntries. This works fine when I run the App on a Windows PC, but when building and running on mono on ubuntu 14.2 no messages are received at LogEntries.
As a second slog sink I have configured console output and this works on Linux.

After turning selfdebug on in serilog I got this Exception logged:

```
2016-05-05T10:55:00 Exception while emitting periodic batch from Serilog.Sinks.Logentries.LogentriesSink: System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult ar, Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (IAsyncResult result) [0x0003b] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00057] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00011] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0000e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost) [0x00007] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Serilog.Sinks.Logentries.LeClient.Connect () [0x00049] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Serilog.Sinks.Logentries.LogentriesSink.EmitBatch (IEnumerable`1 events) [0x00023] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink.OnTick () [0x00051] in <filename unknown>:0 
2016-05-05T10:55:02 Exception while emitting periodic batch from Serilog.Sinks.Logentries.LogentriesSink: System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult ar, Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (IAsyncResult result) [0x0003b] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00057] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00011] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0000e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost) [0x00007] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Serilog.Sinks.Logentries.LeClient.Connect () [0x00049] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Serilog.Sinks.Logentries.LogentriesSink.EmitBatch (IEnumerable`1 events) [0x00023] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink.OnTick () [0x00051] in <filename unknown>:0 
2016-05-05T10:55:13 Exception while emitting periodic batch from Serilog.Sinks.Logentries.LogentriesSink: System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult ar, Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (IAsyncResult result) [0x0003b] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <filename Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
unknown>:0
```

Which looks like there is an SSL Issue in combination between Mono and Logentries.

Comment: Just noting this is cross-posted to: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-logentries/issues/4

Answer (score 1):

It may just be easier to use the [Linux Agent](https://logentries.com/doc/linux-agent) to follow the log file which is created. The Agent would then forward this log data to your Account.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a very helpful hint, especially as it also logs system data